# Why can't emacs-lsp go-mode not find go executable in path?

Tags: go, emacs, emacs-lsp

In emacs, using gopls but it cannot find `go` on my path. But it's there, I can run it. Reaching out to the community to see if I'm missing something. I can run a basic gin server without issue.

Using this [config](https://github.com/golang/tools/blob/master/gopls/doc/emacs.md), from docs.

Output:

```txt
panic: err: exec: "go": executable file not found in $PATH: stderr: 

goroutine 73 [running]:
golang.org/x/tools/internal/lsp/debug.PrintVersionInfo.func2()
    /Users/seanh/go/pkg/mod/golang.org/x/tools@v0.0.0-20200407041343-bf15fae40dea/internal/lsp/debug/info.go:58 +0x1c3
golang.org/x/tools/internal/lsp/debug.section(0x1a2d520, 0xc00013de60, 0x0, 0x18cda9a, 0x7, 0xc0003bb588)
    /Users/seanh/go/pkg/mod/golang.org/x/tools@v0.0.0-20200407041343-bf15fae40dea/internal/lsp/debug/info.go:69 +0x319
golang.org/x/tools/internal/lsp/debug.PrintVersionInfo(0x1a40560, 0xc000226c60, 0x1a2d520, 0xc00013de60, 0x1, 0x0)
    /Users/seanh/go/pkg/mod/golang.org/x/tools@v0.0.0-20200407041343-bf15fae40dea/internal/lsp/debug/info.go:52 +0x1a7
golang.org/x/tools/internal/lsp.(*Server).initialized(0xc000230080, 0x1a40560, 0xc000226c60, 0x1fa2ef0, 0x0, 0x0)
    /Users/seanh/go/pkg/mod/golang.org/x/tools@v0.0.0-20200407041343-bf15fae40dea/internal/lsp/general.go:163 +0x1a3
golang.org/x/tools/internal/lsp.(*Server).Initialized(0xc000230080, 0x1a40560, 0xc000226c60, 0x1fa2ef0, 0x1fa2ef0, 0x0)
    /Users/seanh/go/pkg/mod/golang.org/x/tools@v0.0.0-20200407041343-bf15fae40dea/internal/lsp/server_gen.go:112 +0x49
golang.org/x/tools/internal/lsp/protocol.ServerHandler.func1(0x1a40560, 0xc000226c60, 0xc00022cd80, 0x1c650b5, 0x1f77a40)
    /Users/seanh/go/pkg/mod/golang.org/x/tools@v0.0.0-20200407041343-bf15fae40dea/internal/lsp/protocol/tsserver.go:97 +0x757
golang.org/x/tools/internal/lsp/lsprpc.handshaker.func1(0x1a40560, 0xc000226c60, 0xc00022cd80, 0x0, 0x0)
    /Users/seanh/go/pkg/mod/golang.org/x/tools@v0.0.0-20200407041343-bf15fae40dea/internal/lsp/lsprpc/lsprpc.go:531 +0x505
golang.org/x/tools/internal/jsonrpc2.MustReply.func1(0x1a40560, 0xc000226c60, 0xc00022cd80, 0x1007aaf, 0xc0002901d8)
    /Users/seanh/go/pkg/mod/golang.org/x/tools@v0.0.0-20200407041343-bf15fae40dea/internal/jsonrpc2/handler.go:54 +0x47
golang.org/x/tools/internal/jsonrpc2.AsyncHandler.func1.2(0xc00009eb40, 0xc000226de0, 0xc000232130, 0x1a40560, 0xc000226c60, 0xc00022cd80)
    /Users/seanh/go/pkg/mod/golang.org/x/tools@v0.0.0-20200407041343-bf15fae40dea/internal/jsonrpc2/handler.go:110 +0x6c
created by golang.org/x/tools/internal/jsonrpc2.AsyncHandler.func1
    /Users/seanh/go/pkg/mod/golang.org/x/tools@v0.0.0-20200407041343-bf15fae40dea/internal/jsonrpc2/handler.go:107 +0x187

Process gopls stderr finished
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A guess:  The `PATH` env var might be different in Emacs compared to whatever other shell you're running.  You can check with `(getenv "PATH")` in Emacs, and you can set it with

```
(setenv "PATH" (concat (getenv "PATH") ":/path/to/go"))
```

Also if you start Emacs from the same shell that can find `gopls`, Emacs should have the same `PATH` var and everything should work.

As far as *why* the `PATH`s are different, it has to do with how you start Emacs and your shell.